# Form POST in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

I'm trying to convert a classic ASP page to ASP.NET 3.5. The page has several forms on it for several different things.

In ASP.NET, there's a server form control wrapping the entire page, and form controls don't work within a server form control, and you can't have more than one server form control on a page.

So in order to keep this functionality, I can either:

- Remove the server form control that's wrapping the page, and leaving the html forms on the page.
- Create button click events for every form and perform the POST in the code-behind.

What's the preferred method here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wonder if converting to vanilla asp.net (aka webforms) is a bad idea here. Personally I'd go to MVC instead - allows multiple forms etc, and the views are much closer to he HTML, a lot like ASP.

I guess I'm saying there are some glitches vanilla asp.net introduces that you don't **have** to suffer.

Comment: I agree with this. If you have a choice, choose MVC. It is easy to learn, and I imagine you will be up and running quicker than you would trying to hack everything to work with Web Forms. Plus you'll benefit from having a much cleaner and maintainable design. Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree in this case, even though I personally prefer WebForms.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the second option, any button click is going to post the whole page back anyway so you're not saving any bandwidth.  Simply handle each button appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer I provided to a similar question here :-)

[How to get past embedding a html form for paypal buttons asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320966/how-to-get-past-embedding-a-html-form-for-paypal-buttons-asp-net/3431566#3431566)

If you're going to use different button clicks, you still need to use this override to disable the non-related buttons in each handler, otherwise it won't work. You can only have one form tag at a time - this way you can toggle/disable the ones you're not using as appropriate.

Better still, refactor your application to use a single form. While MVC would be a closer match to the model you're using right now, it wouldn't make sense to go that route unless you were experienced enough with it; Web Forms is an easier jump.